# UITextField custom clear button jumps on layoutIfNeeded

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image: gif]

I've a custom clear button for text field. This button jumps from left to right if I use `layoutIfNeeded` in keyboard show function. It happens only first time I edit text field, doesn't happen on subsequent edit. How do I fix it? I need `layoutIfNeeded` for smooth animation.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: CustomTextField!

    @objc func handleKeyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

        // calculate height etc....

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // This causes clear button to jump
        })

    }
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialize()

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // other code
    }

    func initialize() {
        self.text = ""
        self.setPlaceHolderTextFontAndColour(text: self.placeholder!, font: UIFont.body, colour: .lightGray)

        let clearButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
        clearButton.setImage(UIImage.clearButton, for: [])

        self.rightView = clearButton
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clearClicked(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.clearButtonMode = .never
        self.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try in your `CustomTextField` class (if you don't need other animations there)

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me and doesn't have much of side effects. I'm still having some issues with jumps though will continue to investigate further.

Comment: Also you can use UIView.animate(withDelay: ...) - this is the superbest solution, but in some cases can be useful.

Comment: You mean to say add UIView.animate(withDelay: ...) in the code above instead of     super.layoutSubviews()
    }

Comment: no, I'm about using in general. For example, if you want to animate something other after  some animated event (keyboard didAppear for example).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like something I'd call an actual bug. Of course, I could be wrong...

One way that could fix it:

In your custom text field's `initialize()` code, set `self.rightViewMode = .always`, then add this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if self.rightViewMode == .always {
        self.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    }
}
```

I've only done quick testing, but it seems to do the job.

Side note: any view you add in Storyboard is automatically loaded with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`, so you do not need to do that in your `awakeFromNib()` func.

Comment: Just to update that it does work but it introduces another swing issue - cursor swings from left to right if there is text entered in the text fields. Alex's solution works better.